# Is there a way to get AWS Aurora Mysql 5.7 compatible to cause timestamps to be updated to current timestamp when null is explicitly passed in?

Tags: mysql-5.7, aws-aurora

All examples are technically from AWS RDS Aurora Mysql compatible, however I believe the issue is the same for non-aws mysql.
In Mysql 5.6 and 5.7 with the exact same values for sql_mode (the 5.6 defaults) and explicit_defaults_for_timestamp=1 and with a table defined like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `myexample` (
  `myexampleid` bigint(30) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `Updated` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`myexampleid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5400 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

and a row that looks like

```
1    2022-01-01 00:01:01    2022-01-01 00:01:01
```

in 5.6 the query `update myexample SET Updated=NULL WHERE myexampleid=1;`
will cause the row to change to

```
1    2022-01-01 00:01:01    2022-06-30 18:00:21
```

or whatever the current_timestamp is at the moment the query is run.

In 5.7 the same query will cause the row to change to

```
1    2022-01-01 00:01:01    0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

Is there any setting or combination of settings that would bring back the previous much more intuitive behavior of 5.6.

I get that setting an explicit null when you want a default is bad practice, but I'm looking for an interim fix until the developers can fix the code.